# In Rails, how can I have a list of commands automatically run say every 24 hours?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a backend Rails JSON API.

Every X amount of hours, there is some data I would like to purge.

So I need to be able to run some commands every X hours.

How can I accomplish this in Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) is a Ruby gem that provides a clear syntax for writing and deploying cron jobs.

It is an easy way to write cron jobs to a cron tab file which is later on executed by the system. It provides you a nice DSL to schedule your tasks.

Let's assume you have a `test` action in `YourModel` that you want to run every 24 hours, so you will be doing this:

*your_model.rb*

```
def test
    # Do Something...
end
```

*schedule.rb*

```
every 24.hours do
  runner 'YourModel.test'
end
```

You need to run the following command on your project to do create the crontab:

```
whenever -i
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this gem whenever (https://github.com/javan/whenever), which will help you manage scheduling using crontab.